# Sum All Values in Array and Output Result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL query which outputs the following table:

Table contains

```
Customer  | Value
Customer1 | 50
Customer2 | 1354
```

I wish to sum both values from table using array_sum.

**My current code:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

$data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);

$total = array_sum($data['Value']);
echo $total;
```

I get the following error:

```
array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, double given in etc
```

Comment: You only fetched one row so only one Value.

Comment: Would you know how to bring all rows?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver "Returns a row as an array" - What the OP needs would be a *column* as an array.

Comment: @chris85 Maybe because that would require a second roundtrip to the DB?

Comment: I wanted to avoid multiple SQL queries as I am outputting the table results in a table

Comment: Oh so there is more happening with this code than displayed? How about `$total += $data['Value'];` and initialize `$total` as `0`.

Comment: Who keeps downvoting here, and why?

Comment: Yes sorry @chris85 I am doing a bit more with it and thought rather than another SQL query I would sum the array - but proving difficult so far.

Comment: @HannoBinder: There is an example showing how to LOOP and fetch all rows.

Comment: If you output the sum only after the whole table you can just keep summing up each row as you iterate over it for output, then finally output the sum.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Hmm, I may have misunderstood the question then. Thought the OP was outputting the table anyway, but he didn't actually say that.

Comment: @chris85 sorry the += didn't work I'm still only getting the first result of the table.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - so what your saying is I should while the  array then sum? I struggle to understand how I can sum a while statement array?

Comment: Take a look at answer below, hopefully that clears up the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), the `array_sum` expects an array, not a string.

Your code also currently is only working with one record. You need to loop the fetch to get all records.

This should give you the sum.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
$total = 0;
while($data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)) {
     $total += $data['Value'];
    //other stuff you are doing with results, otherwise just do SQL sum.
}
echo $total;
```

Another approach would be just selecting the sum via sql.

```
select sum(value) as the_sum from table
```

Then fetch the result and output `the_sum`.

Comment: Beautiful! thank you. There should be more people like you on this site!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = array();
$users = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

$data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {

    $users[] = $row;

}
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $sum[] = $user['value'];
}
echo $total = array_sum($sum);
```